# definition of a function: NOTATION CHECK

Tags: functions, notation

Let $X,Y$ $\subset$ $\mathbb{R}$ where $x \in X$ and $f: X \to Y$. Would it be correct to say:

"We may define what the map $f$ does by describing how all the domain elements are mapped to their images" (e.g. $f(x)=x^2$).

I just want to make sure this is the correct way to word what a function does.

Comment: That is fine.  Alternatively you can write $x\mapsto x^2$.  As a nitpick though, you used "i.e." when you meant to use "e.g."  The first, "i.e.", is used like you would use the phrase "in other words" while "e.g." is used like you would use the phrase "for example."

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you very much for your feedback, I corrected the I.e. in the post. That helped a lot!

Comment: e.g. is *exempli gratia* (Latin, for (the sake of) example) and i.e. is *id est* (Latin, that is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your definition is fine. Although, I will add some more detail to the definition of a function.

A function is a mapping from the set $X$ (the domain) into a set $Y$ (the range).

It maps every element $x\in X$ to an element $y \in Y$. Often the mapping is given through a formula:

$$f:X\to Y, ~f(x)=x^2$$

What is written above is the official way to specify a function: the domain, range, and mapping formula are explicitly specified. As suggested through a comment, you could also write $x\mapsto x^2$ instead of $f(x)=x^2$. In some textbooks and course notes, it is often assumed that the domain and range are implicitly understood $(X,Y\subset\mathbb R)$ and we write $f(x)=x^2$. The domain is everything where the formula makes sense and the range is where the formula takes the domain to.

Observe that we don't need to define a function through a formula such as $f(x)=x^2$ or $f(x)=2x+3$. We could also define a function $f:X\to Y$ by

$$f(2) = 7,~f(3) = 1,~f(5) = 11,~f(7) = 3,~f(11) = 9$$

or a function $g:[0,1] \to (\{0\},\{1\})$ by

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} 
      0 & \text{if x is rational} \\
      1 & \text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}
$$

It is important to understand that a function assigns to every element of the domain *exactly one* element of the range. This restriction isn't placed on the range. A function can map two different elements of the domain to the same element of the range.

Comment: Gotcha! Would it be okay to say: "We may define the map $f$ by a rule that  describes how all the domain elements are mapped to their images"?  Where $f$ is defined by the rule $f(x)=x^2$. @Axion004

Comment: @TaylorRendon Yes, if $f:X \to Y$ then $Y$ would be the image of $f$. The function $f(x)=x^2$ would input a real number and output its square. So, the domain would be $\mathbb R$ while the image would be $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @Axionn004 Wonderful! Thank you for your time on my post.